# C# How to know the index value of a List of type Image?

Tags: c#, .net

**Problem:**

I just want to get and display the index(in numeric value) of an Image type List.
I tried to google it but most of the List example are Int type.

**Here is my code:** NOTE: I put "**?**"

```
 foreach (Image currentImage in imageList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Image Found({0}) : {1}",?,currentImage.Source));
        }
```

What to supply on the "**?**" of my MessageBox to get numeric valued index?

**I should get this kind of Ouput display:**

Image Found **1**:"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Image1.jpg"

Image Found **2**:"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Image2.jpg"

Image Found **3**:"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Image3.jpg"

etc..till the end of List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imageList.IndexOf(currentImage) should do the trick.

Comment: This is a bad idea, as it requires iterating the list for every element!

Comment: Yes Thank you...This make sense. Im looking to display an index not a counter like other's suggestions because I'll be using this solution to some part my code..

Comment: I agree that its not the most efficient way of doing it with the code example given, but he was asking how to get the index of an image in his list.

Answer (score 1):

use a for loop

```
for (int i=0;i<imageList.Count;++i)
{             
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Image Found({0}):{1}",(i+1),imageList[i].Source));         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could use a `for` loop and index into your list, a simple counter will work for any `IEnumerable`:

```
 int i = 1;
 foreach (Image currentImage in imageList)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Image Found({0}) : {1}",
                                   i++, // this increments i
                                   currentImage.Source));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. I miss to specify that Ill be using the actual index not just a incremental counter.. sorry but I got it now.. I really appreciate your help